Flink internal datatype processed as generic type
I have a project which would need a flexible datatype within Flink to flow through the operators that can take up some user schema and perform common computations on it, I leaned towards the Row (org.apache.flink.types.Row) datatype as it's internal to Flink may be easier to work with. However, I got an error trying to create a row datatype within the Datastream API, notably
11:52:43,362 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - Field Row#fieldByName will be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution.
11:52:43,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - class java.util.LinkedHashMap does not contain a getter for field accessOrder
11:52:43,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - class java.util.LinkedHashMap does not contain a setter for field accessOrder
11:52:43,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - Class class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution.
11:52:43,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - Field Row#positionByName will be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution.
11:52:43,363 INFO  org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor            [] - class org.apache.flink.types.Row is missing a default constructor so it cannot be used as a POJO type and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance and schema evolution.

I see that the Row type misses a default constructor, but it wouldn't make sense that Row can only be serialized by Kryo, I'm not sure what I'm missing here

The Row type is used by Flink's Table API. I've never tried using it with a vanilla DataStream-based application. What happens if you include the standard set of Flink table jars? Wondering if there's some implicit registration of RowSerializer going on.

Included the flink-table package in my pom and it seems like the same problem is still occuring

I assume you provided type information for the Row, as otherwise it will be processed as a generic type. See https://flink.apache.org/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol.-1-choosing-your-serializer-if-you-can/#row-data-types

Yes that is correct, my DeserializationSchema provides type info

The Flink Table/SQL uses RowData for records flowing through DataStreams, so I would try one of the concrete implementations. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/data/RowData.html
